# Node.js - socket.io web app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've created a basic node.js server program and used socket.io to pass some field data from a client (see below). Pretty chuffed as I'm new to this business. I liked this node-express-socket.io approach as its all Javascript and is apparently usable by most browsers (incl' mobile).  The problem is I've kind of fumbled my way through and do not not fully understand what I have created! Two questions...

1) Do I need to use the "//ajax.googleapis.com...jquery..."? This is annoying as the browser will need to have an internet connection to work. Is there another way to access the html doc elements without needing an internet connection?

2) What does the "app.use(express.static...." line do? The "app.get..." function seems to require this to work.

If there are any other general comments about my code please let me have it!

Cheers,

Kirbs

Client side code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect(document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host);
    function clicked(){
        $(function(){
            var makeInput=$('.app').find('#make').val();
            var modelInput=$('.app').find('#model').val();
            socket.emit('make', makeInput);
            socket.emit('model', modelInput);
        });     
    };
</script>
```

Server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('make', function (make) {
    socket.on('model',function (model){
          console.log('recieved message:', make+','+model);  
      });
  });
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you have setup a static web server (see answer 2), you could simply download the jquery source and serve the .js file from there.

2) "app.use(express.static...." configure a static webserver and setting up the http root directory to the directory that your node.js script lives, as indicated by the `__dirname` variable.  For more detail, see [app.use API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

As result, I would recommend you change you `app.use` to:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and place all your static files, including your jquery file(s), under a `public` subdirectory.

Also, your server side code has a dependency on sequence of `make` and `model` which should be changed.  For example, if you switch the emit order to `model` then `make`, you should see that your server's `console.log` will be picking up the make from the previous call.

Instead, try something like:

```
// On server:
socket.on('info', function (info) {
    console.log('recieved message:', info.make+','+info.model);  
});

// On client:
socket.emit('info', { make: makeInput, model: modelInput })
```

Comment: Thanks marcoseu very helpful, I wasn't sure how to 'emit' several strings in one command. If the emitted data was an array of floating point numbers what method would you recommend?

Comment: Try to wrap array in a dictionary: `{ nums: [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]}`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can serve the jQuery library also from your server if you like that better. You should put it in the public/vendor or public/js folder in your project.

2) This is a middleware call from [Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) framework, which uses in turn the Connect middleware stack. Read up on this [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have thought about downloading it and serving it locally! cheers. I have read quite a bit about middleware, but am not convinced I understand what the term means. It seems to be mostly associated to tasks which are done 'quietly' by the server. Is there more to it than that?